# Ternary String Bayes Rule

Tags: combinatorics, bayes-theorem

Suppose there is a noisy communication channel in
which either $a$ $0 $ or $a $ $1 $ is sent with the following probabilities:

• Probability a $0$ is sent is $0.4.$

• Probability a $1$ is sent is $0.6.$

• Probability that due to noise, a $0$ is changed to a $1$ during
transmission is $0.2.$

• Probability that due to noise, a $1$ is changed to a $0$ during
transmission is $0.1.$

Suppose that a $1$ is received. What is the probability that a $1$ was
sent?

My attempt:

Let $p(b)$ be a $1$ is received and $p(b)$ be a $1$ is sent.

We want to find $p(b \text{ given that } a)$

So we can use bayes rule and we have $$p(a \text{ given that } b) \cdot \frac{p(b)}{p(a)}$$

$P(b)$ is $.6$?

$P (a \text{ given that } b) 1 -.2$?

$P(a) .4 \cdot .2  + .4 \cdot (1 -.2)$ ?

then just fill it in?

Comment: You need to define _events_, not probabilities.  So  $A = \{\mbox{1 is receied}\}$ and $B = \{\mbox{1 is sent}\}$.  This means "$A$ is the event that 1 is received," and "$B$ is the event that 1 is sent." Also the language of conditional probability is "given that" not "such that." So you want to find $P[B|A]$.

Comment: What does "Ternary" mean in the title?

Comment: Also it is hard to follow your equations when they have no equal signs.  Can you give an equation for $P[B|A]$ (the conditional probability of $B$ given that $A$ occurs), and also explain what $P[A|B]$ is?  It looks like you are saying $P[A|B]=1-.2$ and I do not see how you get that.  I agree that $P[A|B] + P[A^c|B]=1$.

Comment: @henry actually, i think the ternary is a mistake...

Comment: For example, the given information says $$ P[\mbox{receive 0} | \mbox{send 1}] = 0.1$$ and yet you are not using that information anywhere that I can see.

Comment: or is it P[A|B]=1−.1?

Comment: @Michael can you confirm ? This is my first bayes

Comment: What is your reasoning?

Comment: P(A given that 1) so suppose a 1 is sent but it changed to a 0 if we take the complement we should get the actually probability we want or .9??